# Zoom several images

Tags: jquery, image, zooming

I need to zoom images inside different DIVs on hover; I am able to zoom all the images at once, but not exclusively.

https://jsfiddle.net/fwUMx/2094/

```js
$('img').load(function() {
    $(this).data('height', this.height);
}).bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        height: $(this).data('height') * (e.type === 'mouseenter' ? 1.5 : 1)
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    background:black;
}
img {
    display:block; 
    margin:10px; 
    height: 20%;
}
div {
    background:red;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;   
}
```

```html
<div class="imagen">
    <img src="http://files.softicons.com/download/game-icons/super-mario-icons-by-sandro-pereira/ico/Mushroom%20-%201UP.ico">
</div>
<div class="imagen">
    <img src="http://files.softicons.com/download/game-icons/super-mario-icons-by-sandro-pereira/ico/Mushroom%20-%201UP.ico">
</div>
<div class="imagen">
    <img src="http://files.softicons.com/download/game-icons/super-mario-icons-by-sandro-pereira/ico/Mushroom%20-%201UP.ico">
</div>
```

Comment: either i dont understand the question or what you have is working fine https://jsfiddle.net/fwUMx/2095/. i've just upped the jquery version.

Comment: I need that, but when the mouse is hover of <div> not <img>.

Comment: @BG101 updated version here: https://jsfiddle.net/fwUMx/2098/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:-

```
$('img').load(function() {
    $(this).data('height', this.height);
})

$('.imagen').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
    var img = $(this).children('img');
    $(img).stop().animate({
        height: $(img).data('height') * (e.type === 'mouseenter' ? 1.5 : 1)
    });
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/fwUMx/2097/)

You were binding the `mouseenter` `mouseleave` to the `img` and not the parent `div`.